# CSRF check failing due to missing "state" parameter in redirect after authorisation of login dialogue

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'm using the [Facebook login dialogue](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) for login to my website (with the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)), but it always fails the first time a new user authorises the app and succeeds the second time they try.

I'm finding that the `state` parameter isn't being passed back to me in the redirect url after a user authorises my app, which causes the CSRF check to fail in my app (in [`getCode()`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L690) in the SDK).  For what it's worth, the `code` parameter is included.

However, if they follow the dialogue link a second time, it works as expected - no further authorisation click is required, and the redirect url is correct, with both `state` and `code` parameters.

So my question is:

**How can I find out what is causing the `state` to be missing from the redirect after authorisation?**

For reference, my dialogue link looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fconnect&state=4f246904818d682a742c59cbbced829c&scope=email%2Cuser_likes
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/587975411230466 - currently the top bug in Facebook's bug tracker

Comment: Ah, thanks @Igy.  Add that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Also, WTF @ the close vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Igy said, it was a bug on Facebook's side, fixed now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/587975411230466